# Cannot resolve onRequestPermissionResult() method after integrating paypal sdk

Tags: android, fragment, paypal

```
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    fragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

> I have integrated Paypal SDK in my project and after that, I am getting the above error with a red line on `fragment.onRequestPermissionsResult`. Before the integration of PayPal SDK it was all good and suddenly after the integration, this red line popped up. But when I build the gradle, it builds successfully without showing any error in the console but this red line still remains which had stopped my one module working.

Comment: Can show your app gradle file ?

Comment: I am also getting red lines in some other fragments also. Cannot resolve  context in super.onAttach(context)

Comment: `compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'`